# WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL in wp-config.php Someone can help me to understand?

Tags: variables

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content-assecure' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/wp-content-assecure');
```

I moved a site to a new hosting provider. The home page appears blank. I checked the database and everything was ok, I copied all the files to root as present in the source file, I updated the wp-config.php with the new database data.

However, I saw these two lines at the bottom of the wp-config.php that I don't understand, and perhaps this is the origin of the problem why the site doesn't work.
Can anyone help me understand?
Thank you
Paul

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume these were added by your old hosting provider, and are specific to their environments. Try removing those two lines. Without them being set so early, WordPress should set them to the standard locations, which hopefully is what your new host has (which you can check for yourself). Normally these would end in `wp-content`, rather than `wp-content-assecure`.